# How to display a button over a picture only when hovering it?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to reproduce some pieces of CSS from the http://flink.to website, especially the tiles which contains for each article the picture, the title, the author, the link to the author page and the link to the article.

Here is the HTML for one tile :

```
<div class="block-module">

<a href="http://flink.to/stories/54b6e61de3039db33f00000b" class="article-link">
    <span class="button">View Story</span>
</a>

<img src="https://cdn01.flink.to/api/image/54f492ec30323921c9000000/300/300/fill">

<div class="block-about">
    <h2 class="block-title">Arch Enemy’s Perpetual Revolution</h2>
    <span class="block-stats">
    by <a href="http://flink.to/Andrew.Epstein" class="author-link">Andrew Epstein</a>
    </span>
</div>

</div>
```

Here is the CSS for one tile :

```
.block-module { width: 283px; height: 283px; font-size: 0.9622em; display: block; cursor:pointer; border-radius:0.3125em; overflow:hidden; z-index:4; position:relative; }
.block-about { position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; padding:4em 1em 1em 1em; background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0,0,0,0.55), rgba(0,0,0,0.8)); background-image:linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0,0,0,0.55), rgba(0,0,0,0.8)); }
.block-about a { position:relative; z-index:5; }
.block-title { max-width:100%; margin:0 0 0; color: white !important;font-size:1.625em; }
.block-stats { width:100%; margin-top:0.35714em; font-size:0.875em; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.55) !important; }
.button { color:#ffffff; background-color:#337d94; }
.author-link { color:#659dae; }
```

Everything's OK except that we can't access the article and the "view story" link which is supposed to show up only when we hover the picture, in the middle/center of it.

**Edit : Here is a demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/5qwejk20/

As the website's CSS sheet of Flink.to is really very complicated, I didn't find how to resolve this. Could you please help me ?

Comment: The CSS of this button is refering to at least 30 or 40 classes in their CSS sheet. I tried to find the good pieces of CSS, but I finally managed to make it working with more than 100 lines in the CSS. I can understand your answer but if I'm here, it's because I'm stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of CSS, and obviously it's hard to tell what does what and it will need to be trimmed. But from what I can tell these are the styles making it happen. The button opacity is initially 0 (hidden), so needed to change to 1.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qwejk20/2)

I added this style to make it show with the cursor

```
.view-full-module.mod-custom-icon:hover .button.view-full-custom-el {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it is a great help !

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the css the elements are hiding and showing by using the `z-index` property and [CSS Positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp). Try the following code, I use different values of `z-index` to overlap elements. Remember that the `z-index` property only is valid for elements with `position:absolute`,`position:relative` or `position:fixed` so you have to scaffold your website having this on mind. I also added an id to the `img` to select it on the css. http://jsfiddle.net/cfahhmkj/

HTML

```
<div class="block-module">
   <a href="http://flink.to/stories/54b6e61de3039db33f00000b" class="article-link">
     <span class="button">View Story</span>
   </a>

   <img class="albumImage" src="https://cdn01.flink.to/api/image/54f492ec30323921c9000000/300/300/fill">

  <div class="block-about" >
    <h2 class="block-title">Arch Enemy’s Perpetual Revolution</h2>
    <span class="block-stats">
      by <a href="http://flink.to/Andrew.Epstein" class="author-link">Andrew Epstein</a>
    </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.block-module { width: 283px; height: 283px; font-size: 0.9622em; display: block; cursor:pointer; border-radius:0.3125em; overflow:hidden; z-index:4; position:relative; }

.block-about { position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; padding:4em 1em 1em 1em; background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0,0,0,0.55), rgba(0,0,0,0.8)); background-image:linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0,0,0,0.55), rgba(0,0,0,0.8)); }

.block-about a { position:relative; z-index:5; }

.block-title { max-width:100%; margin:0 0 0; color: white !important;font-size:1.625em; }

.block-stats { width:100%; margin-top:0.35714em; font-size:0.875em; color:rgba(255,255,255,0.55) !important; }

.button { color:#ffffff; background-color:#337d94; }

.author-link { color:#659dae; }

.article-link {
  position:absolute;
  left:110px;
  top: 120px;
  z-index:-1;
}
.albumImage{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:0;
}
.albumImage:hover{
  z-index:-2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but as it is, there's no access to the article-link, and the button is flashing when hovering it.

Comment: You are welcome, this was just an example, I hope it helped you. With this approach you have to set also z-indexes to the other elements such as the article-link or its container.